# Golang GPIO Edge Detection with rpio library

Tags: go, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have recently started experimenting on the intersection of software and hardware, by playing with the GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi, with software written in Go. Mostly everything is working out well so far, but there's one thing I can't really wrap my head around yet and that's how to efficiently do edge detection on an input pin and trigger code accordingly.

I am using the [following library (rpio)](https://github.com/stianeikeland/go-rpio) as an abstraction over the raw GPIO layer and it contains functions to start watching for edge events and checking if an edge event occurred. Other libraries seem to employ similar patterns. I can't imagine it's actually intended to be completely poll-based though. Granted I'm new to this, but I'm not new to software development and polling for change seems both inefficient and slow. I could write a simple loop polling for the change maybe a hundred times per second, but it feels wrong. Especially when watching more pins than one.

Therefore I am fairly confident I'm missing or misreading something and I wonder if you can point me into a better direction.

Comment: https://github.com/warthog618/gpiod . It can wait for pins on chardev interface.

Comment: That seems excellent, will try that out. Also looking into periph.io, it also claims to be able to signal edges without a busy loop. Still kinda wondering if I'm misinterpreting how to use the rpio library, but I guess that's of a lesser concern. Thanks!

Comment: Erik, RPi GPIO library was hacked when there was no better interface(s) available. Nowadays it should be abandoned and avoided in any projects. Perhaps they will get it fixed in the future, but why? It’s non-standard, non-portable piece of software.

Comment: Fair enough, it has a convenient API that I liked. I have since switched to the periph.io libs, they're great. gpiod also seems great but was hard to cross compile. Thanks!